# PHP - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

I'm receiving "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"  I'm guessing it's because I'm returning an array of data that isn't inclosed in ( ),( ),( ),..?  How might this be accomplished?

```
<?php 

// open the database connection
require('connection.php');

// build the string to populate the database

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $buffer = "";
 $returnedData = $_POST['data'];

 // escape

 $returnedData = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $returnedData);

 foreach ( $returnedData as $data )

 {
    $buffer .= $data['week_date'];
    $buffer .= $data['crew_chief']; 
    $buffer .= $data['monday_crew'];
    $buffer .= $data['tuesday_crew'];
    $buffer .= $data['wednesday_crew'];
    $buffer .= $data['thursday_crew'];
    $buffer .= $data['friday_crew'];
    $buffer .= $data['saturday_crew'];
    $buffer .= $data['sunday_crew'];
    $buffer .= $data['instrument'];
    $buffer .= $data['monday_location'];
    $buffer .= $data['tuesday_location'];
    $buffer .= $data['wednesday_location'];
    $buffer .= $data['thursday_location'];
    $buffer .= $data['friday_location'];
    $buffer .= $data['saturday_location'];
    $buffer .= $data['sunday_location'];
    $buffer .= ", ";
}

 $buffer = rtrim($buffer, ", ");


} // end if


// perform the database insert

$insertQuery = "INSERT INTO log_dates (";
$insertQuery .= " week_date, crew_chief, monday_crew, tuesday_crew, wednesday_crew, thursday_crew, friday_crew, saturday_crew, sunday_crew, instrument, monday_location, tuesday_location, wednesday_location, thursday_location, friday_location, saturday_location, sunday_location";
$insertQuery .= ") VALUES (";
$insertQuery .= "'{$returnedData}'";
$insertQuery .= ")";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $insertQuery);



// redirect on finish

if ($result) {
    header("Location: http://www..com/");
} else {
    die("Database query failed. " . mysqli_error($connection));
} 

 // close database connection
 mysqli_close($connection);

 ?>
```

Comment: At the very least - echo out your $insertQuery to see what it looks like. You're passing $returnedData into your query as a single variable, but you have sixteen columns listed. And what are you using `$buffer` for?

Comment: where you have used `$buffer` ?

Comment: Try to echo your query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code makes very little sense.

```
$returnedData = $_POST['data'];
```

is all fine and dandy, but then you do

```
$returnedData = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $returnedData);
```

which returns a **STRING**. You then take that string and try to treat it as an array

```
foreach ( $returnedData as $data )
```

and build another string from it.

Then you try to a SQL query... but completely ignore this new string you built

```
$insertQuery = "INSERT INTO log_dates (";
[[...snip...]]
$insertQuery .= "'{$returnedData}'";
$insertQuery .= ")";
```

using this now-mangled former-array-that-is-now-just-a-string.

E.g. you're building a query that looks like

```
INSERT INTO log_dates (long list of fields)
VALUES (a single value here)
```

You're using mysqli... there's no excuse for NOT using a prepared statement with placeholders. There is no need to try and escape your values yourself, especially since you're doing that part completely wrong anyways.

Comment: if I echo my values I receive this: "2013-07-08 - 2013-07-14, Alan, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 2013-07-08 - 2013-07-14, Brad, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,"  Thanks for your help.  I'm missing ( ) around each set?  Can I add this?

Comment: you're wrapping those values in `'`, so the entire string gets slammed down into a single value. even if you removed the `'`, you'd STILL have sql problems, because `2013-07-08` needs to be INDIVIDUALLY quoted, otherwise it'll be a math problem. 2013 minus 7 minus 8 = 1998, `Alan` be treated as a field, not a name, etc... you really need to go read up on prepared statements and placeholders. your code is downright dangerous right now.

Comment: Maybe I'll use prepared statements like you advised.